# NullPointerException when building SessionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate

I've created a simple example of a class with Hibernate, but I get the following errors:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed. java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.reset(Configuration.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:220)
    at it.univaq.mwt.tplabs0.Test.main(Test.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:585)
    ... 4 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at it.univaq.mwt.tplabs0.Test.main(Test.java:20)
```

My Test class:

```java
package it.univaq.mwt.tplabs0;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

    try {
      sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
      System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed. " + ex);
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    System.out.println("Creating element");
    Element el = new Element("prova", 1);

    session.save(el);
    System.out.println("Committing Tx");
    session.getTransaction().commit();

    System.out.println("Closing Session");
    if (session.isOpen())
        session.close();
  }
}
```

My Hibernate configuration file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">master</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">master</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
     <mapping class="it.univaq.mwt.tplabs0.Element" resource="it/univaq/mwt/tplabs0/Element.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My Libraries:

- antlr-2.7.6.jar
- asm.jar
- asm-attrs.jar
- c3p0-0.9.1.jar
- cglib-2.2.jar
- commons-collections-3.1.jar
- commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
- concurrent-1.3.2.jar
- connector.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- ehcache-1.2.3.jar
- hibernate3.jar
- jaas.jar
- javassist.jar
- jboss-cache.jar
- jboss-common.jar
- jboss-jmx.jar
- jboss-system.jar
- jdbc2_0-stdext.jar
- jgroups-2.2.8.jar
- jta.jar
- log4j-1.2.15.jar
- oscache-2.1.jar
- proxool-0.8.3.jar
- swarmcache-1.0rc2.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
- slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar

Launching this simple execution I get the error from above. The database I'm using is Oracle 11g.

What happened?

Comment: Your SessionFactory object is not getting Created

Comment: Are you using Eclipse IDE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code says :

```
   1. SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
   2.   try {
   3.     sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
   4.   } catch (Throwable ex) {
   5.     System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed. " + ex);
   6.     ex.printStackTrace();
   7.   }
   8.          
   9.   Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        // Here you are trying to access the Session which is not even created
```

You are trying to access the Session which is either not configured in CurrentSessionContext or not created at all.

Replace your code at line number 9 with :

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

And you will see yourself through.

Comment: I replaced Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); with Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(); but the error is the same :(

Comment: I solved the problem by deleting the user library "hibernate" and loading the libraries in the classpath directly (Java build path --> add external jar)!

Comment: Yes, Eclipse seems to have this problem while using User libraries and that's why I asked you about that. Anyway, good to see you through the problem you're facing. Cheers !